# I'm the Teamleader (not GM) and one of my Team members is a total jerk

Tags: group-dynamics, shadowrun, helping

I'm the leader with a total of 4 (included me) man group which 2 of the member agree me as the leader. Even the name of the group is related to my own name. 
One of my Members is a reaaaal jerk (ingame) to my character and it's our first time playing shadowrun (or any P&P).

So in-game I really want to punch him, not only because he is disrespectful, also my character is racist against his race (but it would probably kill him with one punch).

He also caused trouble getting the last mission and we got less money for it and my other team members are very passive about it and he wouldn't even agree on getting a bit less money for it. (I paid already a lot of my own money in the last missions, for the team).

So how can I handle a not cooperative team member who is disrespectful against his team leader? (I can't just kick him because that would ruin the whole game for the group).

Comment: related : http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conflict between player-characters is a double-edged sword. Depending on how the players deal with it and how well the campaign and game system supports it, it can either add a very interesting aspect to the game or ruin it completely.

Which level of conflict you want between the player-characters is something the group should agree on before the campaign. Possible variants are:

- Player-characters must be nice to each other at all times and act as a team as well as they can.
- Player-characters can have verbal conflicts and ideological disagreements for show, but still need to act in the interest of the team.
- Player-characters follow their own agendas and may put them over those of the party (just make sure [you don't let them get in the way of a good story](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it)). PC-on-PC violence might happen, but should be very well-justified in-character and out-of-character and rather the exception than the norm.
- Player-characters are direct opponents. Defeating each other is the goal of the game.

Apparently you are further up in that list, while the other player is further down. When there is a misunderstanding about which of these variants is expected among the group members, it can negatively affect the game experience of everyone. That's why it's important to agree on it and then stick to it. Also, the GM must be aware of the tone and plan accordingly. When the PCs might turn on each other at any time and the GM doesn't have a contingency plan for this situation, the whole campaign might fall apart.

Regarding your current campaign: If your group agrees on a cooperative playstyle from now on, and the personality of some of your characters are simply not designed for that, there are two options your group (including GM) can agree on:

- Change the characters to have more compatible personalities. If necessary, decide retroactively that certain problematic events have never happened. Yes, you can do that. It's your game.
- In agreement with the players remove the problematic character(s) from your party, then replace them with new characters. Kicking them out actually *is* an option. When everyone hates the guy, he might even return as an NPC villain, which could turn out as a really awesome RP moment (maybe he was a mole all along?). Or just have them die.

But whatever course of action you take, get buy-in from the player first. Just removing their character from the game without their consent and handing them a new sheet to fill out won't be a very nice and mature way to handle the situation.

Comment: so you think i should change my own charakter to manage him better?
if that's a deal i would think about it but i really dont know if he would behave better after i start beeing more nice to him.
he kinda really hates me but i dont know all the background of his character.

Comment: @dennisschütz actually I was talking about convincing the other player to change *their* character. But if your character has certain traits which give *other character* a good reason to hate him, changing that might also be an option. Whatever leads to a working party. Which character is actually the problem is something you need to figure out by talking to each other (out-of-character).

Comment: @phillipp Im pretty sure he wont change his character. His problem is he can't recognize me (or anyone) as his leader (i think thats dumb since we are a group/friends for years ingame). But i might have a serious ingame talk to him, thanks for your hints and advices.

Comment: @dennisschütz I think it would be better to have a serious out-of-game talk first to find out what your expectations for the game are and how you can find a compromise.

Comment: @dennisschütz By the way: If your group wants scifi and a player-vs-player gamestyle, you might want to take a look at the [tag:Paranoia] game system.

Comment: This answer focuses on pure jerkiness but the OP seems to be strongly hinting that it's more of a "character who doesn't want a boss" issue, which I think is a different thing, and there's some answers on this SE about e.g. military roleplaying that touch on that problem more specifically.

Comment: should i edit the response of my solution when i talked to my mates? 
Or does no one care about how evrything has gone?
If yes, i'll post it on sunday evening